# OCR library to recognize numbers on meter device

Tags: java, android, c++, ocr

I need OCR library(preferably in Java), which will be able to determine digit visualized on meter devices. Please see image. I've tried some libraries in Java but they was not able to determine this kind of font.

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**
Tesseract and Asprise libraries failed to perform this task

Comment: Can you update the question with what libraries you tried and in what way they failed? It may prove useful both to the ones answering and to future visitors of this page.

Comment: good point, I've updated already

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could take a look at [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/), it's a Google maintained open source OCR. However, I think that if you just supply the image as it is the OCR might have some issues, reason being that you have digits which vary in size, and this will most likely cause issues while the Neural Network(s) are learning.

So, I think that you would have a larger chance of success if you filter your image first and try to remove items that you do not need to identify and try to make the digits you need to read the same size.

EDIT: As per your edit, you can also take a look at [Java OCR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/):

> Java OCR is a suite of pure java libraries for image processing and
>   character recognition. Small memory footprint and lack of external
>   dependencies makes it suitable for android development. Provides
>   modular structure for easier deployment

That being said, I still think that you should do some processing on your image first.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that image processing should be done before trying to recognize the characters in it.